# what is the expectation value of a sum of absolute values of random variables?

Tags: probability, distributions, expected-value

let $M = \langle |m_1 + m_2+...+m_N| \rangle, M^{\prime} = \langle |m_1| + |m_2| +...+|m_N| \rangle$ and $M^{''} = \langle |m_1| \rangle$, where $m_i$ are random variables. and $\langle...\rangle$ represents expectation value. is there any relationship between values $M, M^{'}$ and $M^{''}$?

other information:

$\langle m_1 + m_2+...+m_N \rangle = 0$.

$m_i$ are identical random variables but they are correlated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trivial relationship is $M \leq M' = NM''$, where the second equation follows from linearity of expectation(LE). It looks that we cannot say much more than that in the general case.

Note that, again, from LE, we have $⟨m_{i}⟩ = 0$, for each $i = 1 \ldots N$.

Comment: Although these relationships are true, I believe they can be tightened substantially.  (For instance, consider the squares of $M$ and $M^\prime$ and relate them to covariances.)  It would be especially interesting to explore the case where the common marginal distribution of the $m_i$ has finite variance, raising the possibility that a tight inequality can be established in terms of the correlation matrix.